# Implement Hyphen Between Each Digit in Output

Tags: java

So I'm writing a program that mimics a phone keypad, whereas it would convert a string of text to integers: abc(2), def(3), ghi(4), jkl(5), mno(6), pqrs(7), tuv(8), wxyz(9). Except the output should have hyphens(-) between the digits.

Example input: `Alabama`

Output: `2-5-2-2-2-6-2`

But my code only outputs `2522262`. How would I go about formatting this correctly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneKeypad {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(getNumbers(str));
}

private static final char[] DIGITS = ( 
      // ABC     DEF
        "222" + "333"
    + // GHI     JKL     MNO
        "444" + "555" + "666"
    + // PQRS     TUV     WXYZ
        "7777" + "888" + "9999").toCharArray();

public static String getNumbers(CharSequence   s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
        if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
            result.append(DIGITS[c - 'A']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: append '-' to your result and handle the case where i=s.length() - 1. ie remove the trailing -.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-` after each digit. Easiest way I see, change

```
result.append(DIGITS[c - 'A']);
```

to

```
result.append(DIGITS[c - 'A']).append('-');
```

Then remove the last `-` when you return like,

```
public static String getNumbers(CharSequence s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 2); // <-- digit-digit...
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
        if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
            result.append(DIGITS[c - 'A']).append('-');
        }
    }
    if (result.length() > 1) {
        result.setLength(result.length() - 1);
    }
    return result.toString(); // <-- Don't forget to return the result.
}
```

You might find it easier if you pass in `s`, you could call `toUpperCase()` and `toCharArray()` and then use a `for-each` loop. Like,

```
public static String getNumbers(String s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 2);
    for (char c : s.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') { // <-- I find this test easier to read, 
                                    //     but that's just my opinion.
            result.append(DIGITS[c - 'A']).append('-');
        }
    }
    if (result.length() > 1) {
        result.setLength(result.length() - 1);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: OP may want to check that `result.length >= 1`

Comment: @Frisch Ok awesome! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Solid advice.